# If we have the product of 3 primes, two of them large and one small, can we find the small one through factorization?

Tags: prime-factorization

If we have the product of 3 primes,
 A*B*s
 two of them large: A, B 
and one small: s
We don t know the product of A*B,
 (Given that if we knew A*B we couldn t factorize it, because of the size and the computational complexity of the problem.)
can we find the small number s through factorization?
 Is there an algorithm with less computational complexity than factoization of A*B, to find s in A*B*s, when we don t know A*B?

Comment: If $s$ is small enough, you could just go through all primes from $2$ onward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use elliptic curve factorization, although it is better when the number also has many factors:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization

Comment: Really interesting! It took me some more time to understand but it seems the ultimate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $s$ is known to be $\le N$, where $N$ is not too big, you can take the gcd of $ABs$ and the product of all primes $\le N$.

Comment: Well, I understood this. Thanks.